# How to get whatsapp Contacts from Android Programmatically?

Tags: android, contacts, android-contacts, whatsapp, android-contentresolver

I have to try to get WhatsApp contacts from phone and I get a total Count of WhatsApp contact but from `RawContacts` how to get WhatsApp numbers and names that I don't know. I have tried to find a solution but can't get the exact solution for that. Please help me.

**I put my code below.**

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();

Cursor c = cr.query(
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTENT_URI,
                        new String[] { ContactsContract.RawContacts.CONTACT_ID, ContactsContract.RawContacts.DISPLAY_NAME_PRIMARY },
                        ContactsContract.RawContacts.ACCOUNT_TYPE + "= ?",
                        new String[] { "com.whatsapp" },
                        null);

                ArrayList<String> myWhatsappContacts = new ArrayList<>();

                String projection[] = { ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER };

                if(c != null) {
                    if (c.getCount() > 0) {
                        while (c.moveToNext()) {

                            String whatsappContactId = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.RawContacts.Data._ID));

                            Cursor dataCursor = cr.query(
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,
                                    projection,
                                    ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID + " = ?",
                                    new String[]{whatsappContactId}, null);
                            // You can also read RawContacts.CONTACT_ID to read the
                            // ContactsContract.Contacts table or any of the other related ones.
                            String number = dataCursor.getString(dataCursor.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NORMALIZED_NUMBER));
                            myWhatsappContacts.add(number);

                        }
                    }
                }

                showLogI(TAG, " WhatsApp contact size :  " + myWhatsappContacts.size());
```

Comment: Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994455/how-to-get-whats-app-contacts-phone-numbers) question will help?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to get whats app contacts' phone numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30994455/how-to-get-whats-app-contacts-phone-numbers)